# How to make a list of integer vectors in R

Tags: r

Basic question: In R, how can I make a list and later populate it with vector elements?

```
l <- list() 
l[1] <- c(1,2,3)
```

This gives the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length", so R is trying to unpack the vector. The only way I have found to work so far is to add the vectors when making the list.

```
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to `?"["` (under the section "recursive (list-like) objects"):

```
 Indexing by ‘[’ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of
 the specified element(s).

 Both ‘[[’ and ‘$’ select a single element of the list.  The main
 difference is that ‘$’ does not allow computed indices, whereas
 ‘[[’ does.  ‘x$name’ is equivalent to ‘x[["name", exact =
 FALSE]]’.  Also, the partial matching behavior of ‘[[’ can be
 controlled using the ‘exact’ argument.
```

Basically, for lists, `[` selects more than one element, so the replacement must be a list (not a vector as in your example).  Here's an example of how to use `[` on lists:

```
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
l[1] <- list(1:2)
l[1:2] <- list(1:3,4:5)
```

If you only want to replace one element, use `[[` instead.

```
l[[1]] <- 1:3
```

Answer (score 25):

Use `[[1]]` as in

```
l[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
l[[2]] <- 1:4
```

and so.  Also recall that preallocation is much more efficient, so if you know how long your list is going to be, use something like

```
l <- vector(mode="list", length=N)
```